# Icon shows black dots in windows mobile 6

Tags: windows, mobile, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6

I'm having problems with the Icon displayed on Start menu, my icon shows some black dots inside the ico image.

I opened this on Visual Studio and in IconFx but there are no black dots.

I tried this on a Windows Mobile 5 and everything was fine.

Does anyone have a clue why this is happening?

Thanks in advance as always!

Comment: What the _heck_ are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out, the resolution on the icon was lower than the expected, the resolution should be 90 x 90 pixels.

Also you should reset your device because the icon stays in cache even if the program has been uninstalled.